How to link the header file of a Template class to its implementation file and then use it in a program via g++ compiler in command prompt?
Here is my file directory:

Here is code inside the header file Foo.hpp for the Template Class Foo:
//Foo.hpp
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP

template <typename Iterable>
class Foo{
    public:
        Iterable* attr_itb;
        Foo(Iterable* itb);
};

#endif

Here is code inside the implementation file Foo.cpp for the Template Class Foo
//Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.hpp"

template <typename Iterable>
Foo<Iterable>::Foo(Iterable* itb):
    attr_itb(*itb) {}

Here is the main program that uses the Template Class Foo
//main.cpp
#include "Foo.hpp"
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    Foo<int[]> bar(&arr);
    std::cout<<(bar.attr_itb)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<(&arr)<<std::endl;
}

I have typed the following into windows command prompt:
g++ main.cpp Foo.cpp -o executable
executable

What I expect to see is:
some memory address
the same memory address

However instead I get a linker error:
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Tim_G\AppData\Local\Temp\cctrJee5.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3c):
undefined reference to `Foo<int []>::Foo(int (*) [])'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I would be most grateful if someone could:

explain this error to me
provide the correct program code to link Foo.cpp to Foo.hpp
provide the correct program code to then use template class Foo in main.cpp with the integer array
as the template parameter
provide the correct windows cmd instructions to compile and link Foo.cpp and main.cpp together.

Also Another additional unrelated question (that i probably cant create an entire question about because it will get closed) is:

are .h files better than .hpp because I haven't seen a single programmer yet use .hpp


This question is similar to: Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The linker error you're encountering happens because template classes need to have their implementation in the header file, not in a separate .cpp file. This is due to the way templates are instantiated by the compiler.
Let me explain:

When you declare a template in a header file and define its methods in a .cpp file, the compiler doesn't generate code for the template methods until they are instantiated (i.e., used with a specific type).
However, if the definition of the template methods is in a separate .cpp file, the compiler cannot see the implementation when it needs to instantiate the template in main.cpp. This leads to an "undefined reference" error during the linking stage.

So you should move the implementation of the Foo constructor from Foo.cpp to Foo.hpp.
Besides, I also notice that there are some bugs in your code.
You're passing &arr to the constructor of Foo<int[]>. The type of &arr is int (*)[5] (a pointer to an array of 5 integers), but the constructor expects a pointer to an array of an unspecified size, int (*)[], this will cause an error. And you foget return statement in the main function, a typical bug.
Here is the corrected code, it works well on my computer :
//Foo.hpp
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP

template <typename Iterable>
class Foo{
    public:
        Iterable* attr_itb;
        Foo(Iterable* itb);
};

// Implementation in the header
template <typename Iterable>
Foo<Iterable>::Foo(Iterable* itb):
    attr_itb(itb) {}

#endif

//main.cpp
#include "Foo.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main(){
    std::array<int, 5> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // Use std::array instead
    Foo<std::array<int, 5>> bar(&arr); // Use std::array instead
    std::cout << (bar.attr_itb) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (&arr) << std::endl;
    return 0; // Add return statement
}

g++ main.cpp -o executable
executable


Thanks for the answer. Also the return statement in the main function is not a necessity in c++.

The type of &arr is int (*)[5] (a pointer to an array of 5 integers), but the constructor expects a pointer to an array of an unspecified size, int (*)[], this will cause an error. Upon implementing your change in Foo.hpp but not changing main.cpp my code runs perfectly fine and I do not receive this type error.
